# Use the _meta class to display list of fields from another class

Tags: python, django, class, field

I know we could easily display a list of all fields inside a particular class, e.g. `EmployerProfile`, with

```
[f.name for f in EmployerProfile._meta.get_fields()]
```

Assume that we have another class, e.g. `FinancialProfile`, and which both classes don't derive from each other. I would like from this specific class to access the fields from the other class. I mean I would like to create a list of fields from `EmployerProfile` from inside `FinancialProfile`. How could I do such thing? Is `super()` method is a great way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Classes are objects in Python so you can create or modify them at runtime. What you need is called "Metaclasses", here are some examples:
http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/14/python-metaclasses-by-example

If your classes do not inherit from each other - there is no way to use `super()`.

Here is an example of creating c class B which has a full copy of class A members:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

class A():
    a = 5
    b = 'b'
    c = "test value"

a = A()
print "Class A members:"
print a.a
print a.b
print a.c

# Please note that class B does not explicitly declare class A members
# it is empty by default, we copy all class A methods in __init__ constructor
class B():

    def __init__(self):

        # Iterate class A attributes
        for member_of_A in A.__dict__.keys():
            # Skip private and protected members
            if not member_of_A.startswith("_"):
                # Assign class A member to class B
                setattr(B, member_of_A, A.__dict__[member_of_A])

b = B()
print "Class B members:"
print b.a
print b.b
print b.c
```

This is an example for Python classes, not Django models. For Django model classes the solution may be a different.

Comment: I am using python 2.7. Could you add some stuff that could clarify your answer?